# Pulling variables from lm in R to use predict

Tags: r, lm, predict

Say I run the following `lm`

```
my.model = lm(distance ~ speed, data = my.data)
```

I could do the following to do a one element prediciton

```
predict(my.model, speed = c(40))
```

Here is the situation: I have a `lm` and I know what it does (that it was regression of distance on speed) but I didn't know that the regressor was named speed.  How can I still do predict?

```
predict(my.model, ??? = c(40))
```

I could get the name of the regressor by `names(my.model$coefficients)` but I can't figure out how to pass it into predict

`predict(my.model, names(my.model$coefficients)[2] = c(40))` won't work

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say wont work, can you please expand. Also, what is the shape of `my.data`

Comment: You don't need to use the combine function `c` in `predict(my.model, speed = c(40))`

Comment: Putting `c(…)` around a single number fulfils no purpose.

Comment: Are you sure that `predict(my.model, speed = c(40))` will give you one predicted value back? `predict` expects an object with variables (dataframe or list) as an input. It won't understand what `speed = ` is. Check this example `m = lm(disp~hp, data = mtcars); 
predict(m, hp=c(100)); 
predict(m, newdata = data.frame(hp=100));
predict(m, newdata = list(hp=100))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the builtin `BOD` for the example run `lm` and then pass a one element list 
or data frame to `predict` using `setNames` to set the name appropriately:

```
fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)

predict(fm, setNames(list(5.5), variable.names(fm)[2]))
##        1 
## 17.98929
```

A different approach is not to use `predict` at all. Using `fm` from above:

```
coef(fm) %*% c(1, 5.5)
##          [,1]
## [1,] 17.98929
```

Comment: Congrats, does exactly what I aimed at with less overhead :( haha

Answer (score 1):

Using `iris` as an example

```
myModel = lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
predict(myModel, structure(list(1), .Names = attr(terms(myModel), "term.labels"), class = "data.frame"))
#        1 
#-2.447297
```

---

### Explanation

The independent variable name in `myModel` is recovered using:

```
attr(terms(myModel), "term.labels")
#[1] "Sepal.Length"
```

If we want to dynamically create a `data.frame` with a column named as the independent variable in `myModel`, we do:

```
structure(list(1), .Names = attr(terms(myModel), "term.labels"), class = "data.frame")
#  Sepal.Length
#1            1
```

Then we pass that `data.frame` to the `predict` method for `lm` objects using:

```
predict(myModel, structure(list(1), .Names = attr(terms(myModel), "term.labels"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  What would I do if instead I wanted to do multiple predictions at once?

Instead of list(1) I tried list(c(1:10)) but I was getting an error

Comment: @DSUR `row.names` was the culprit, try instead `predict(myModel, structure(list(1:10), .Names = attr(terms(myModel), "term.labels"), class = "data.frame"))`